# How to couple the Higgs field with $SU(3)$ (and/or $SU(2)$) Yang-Mills theory in numerical simulations?

Tags: higgs, yang-mills, bosons, wilson-loop, lattice-gauge-theory

I'm trying to couple the Higgs field to numerical simulations of pure gauge theory with heatbath and overrelaxation update of link variables. I don't know how to insert the Higgs field into the calculus of staples and Wilson action. In principle Higgs bosons can be added as $SU(3)$ (or $SU(2))$ matrix, but I don't understand how. Can someone help me?